# Is there an API for accessing data from Live Calendar?

Tags: .net, api, calendar, live

The question actually in it. Google Calendar provides a convenient API for access to their data, and whether the same API for Live Calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some information at the [Microsoft Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wlgeneraldev/thread/3b94ca28-81ca-41cb-8ef3-207d1396a62e).

But the answer was posted in 2007.

[Here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/14704044/Getting-Started-Adding-Events-to-Windows-Live-Calendar) I found some more information, hopefully it suits your needs.

Comment: They do not currently have APIs to the Windows Live Calendar.  =(